# Is the average distance of a prime from its nearest square $1/3$ the average distance from the next nearest square?

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Let $l_n = p_n - \lfloor \sqrt{p_n} \rfloor^{2}$ be the gap between a prime and the nearest square before the prime and $u_n= (\lfloor \sqrt{p_n} \rfloor + 1)^{2} - p_n$ be the gap between a prime and the nearest square after the prime. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{m \to \infty}  \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{m}\max(l_n, u_n)}{\sum_{n=1}^{m}\min(l_n, u_n)} \stackrel{?}{=} 3
$$

My experimental data shows that:

$m=1000000$, ratio $=2.999936$

$m= 100000000$, ratio $= 3.000107$

$m= 1000000000$, ratio $= 3.000083$

Comment: Could you give some context for this? Have you looked at whether the same result holds when instead of primes you just consider non-square natural numbers?

Comment: (it's actually fairly easy to prove this result for non-square naturals; would that be useful?)

Comment: As Chris Lewis' comments indicate, your result is actually true for *any* set of integers which are each, on average, equidistant from each other between perfect squares (like the non-square naturals specifically mentioned, since $3\sum_{k=1}^{n}i\approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}((2n+1)-k)$). Although the specific distribution of primes relative to the nearest, and next nearest, perfect squares are AFAIK not specifically known, I believe it's reasonable to assume they are, generally, equally distributed between consecutive perfect squares. If so, this would then explain why you're getting those results.

Comment: There are unsolved conjectures relating to the distribution of primes between consecutive squares; in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture are relevant.

Comment: The numerical results are in fact very promising.